# Couldn't find User with 'id'=1003

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, controller

I have 1000 Tips and 95 Users in my PostgreSQL database and I want the user to be able to create a new Tip and be taken to the show page where they can see the tip name and description along with author information.

However, I am getting the error "Couldn't find User with 'id'=1003" raised on this line `@author_firstname = User.find(params[:id]).first_name`. I'm not sure why it's assigning the user id to the new Tip id, but I want the User's id to be tied to the Tip instead of the Tip id.

Here is my Tips Controller:

```
class TipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tips = Tip.all
  end

  def new
    @tip = Tip.new
  end

  def create
    @tip = Tip.create(tip_params)
    redirect_to "/tips/#{@tip.id}"
  end

  def show
    @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
    @author_firstname = User.find(params[:id]).first_name
    @author_lastname = User.find(params[:id]).last_name
  end

  private
  def tip_params
    params.require(:tip).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

And some of my routes:

```
get '/users/new', to: 'users#new' 
post '/users', to: 'users#create'
get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get 'users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit'
patch 'users/:id', to: 'users#update'

get '/places/:id', to: 'places#show'

get '/tips/new', to: 'tips#new'
post '/tips', to: 'tips#create'
get '/tips/:id', to: 'tips#show', as: 'tip'
```

Comment: What does the relevant route (in your config/routes.rb file) look like? Is there a `:user_id` in the route somewhere? Your trying to do `params[:id]` to find a user, but that contains the Tip id, not a User id.

Comment: I edited the post to include the routes. Also, the show route works for looking at previous Tips users that already have created, just not creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `TipsController`, `params[:id]` will give you the `id` of the `tip` NOT the `id` of the `user`.

As, your `tip` *belongs_to* `user`, so you should be able to get the `user` using this: `@tip.user`

So, your `show` method can be:

```
def show
    @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
    @author_firstname = @tip.user.first_name
    @author_lastname = @tip.user.last_name
end
```

Comment: Now it just says "Couldn't find User with 'id'=" and raises the error on the same line.

Comment: yeah, because you dont have `user_id` in your `params` hash. Can you show the user and tip models and their associations?

Comment: why did you define your routes that way? you should make use of Rails RESTful routes. That will make your life a lot easier and will do a lot of things automatically if you follow Rails conventions.

Comment: User model= `has_many :tips belongs_to :place`. Tips model: `belongs_to :user belongs_to :place`

Comment: Because I am new to Rails and this is my first Rails project

Comment: if tip belongs_to user and you already have the `@tip`, so you should be able to get the user like this: `@tip.user`. I updated my answer, try that and let me know.

Comment: Now the error is `undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass`. Also, I checked in the rails console and the Tip has a `user_id`, not a `user`

Comment: that means, `@tip.user` is `nil` i.e. you don't have a user for this tip. Make sure you have a `user_id` column in your `tips` table in the database. Please see this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association
to see how belongs_to association works.

Comment: I do have a user_id for in the tips schema `t.integer  "user_id"`

Comment: The issue is, when you create a tip, you are not association this with an user. You have to associate the tip to a user in the Tip's `create` action. Currently, you dont have a user associated with the tip, thats why its `nil` and you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you save your tip, you didn't save the current_user id in tip by putting `@tip.user_id = current_user.id` in your create method.

```
class TipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tips = Tip.all
  end

  def new
    @tip = Tip.new
  end

  def create
    @tip = Tip.new(tip_params)
    @tip.user_id = current_user.id
    if @tip.save
      redirect_to "/tips/#{@tip.id}"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
    @author_firstname = @tip.user.first_name
    @author_lastname = @tip.user.last_name
  end

  private
  def tip_params
    params.require(:tip).permit(:name, :description, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Next, you can get user name by calling `@tip.user.first_name`. I hope this help you.